# Cilk++ cilkexample.c = 200 lines in stderr

Tags: c, stdio, cilk

I installed Cilk successfully on my home computer, a 32-bit machine running Ubuntu.  I replicated the process to the best of my knowledge on my 64-bit Ubuntu netbook, excepting, of course, that I downloaded the 64-bit version instead of the 32-bit version.  When attempting to run the very simple cilkexample.c copied below, however, I get very very many errors, all seeming related to it not having access to library files:

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from cilkexample.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:323:26: error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or director\
y
/usr/include/features.h:356:25: error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/features.h:388:23: error: gnu/stubs.h: No such file or directory
In file included from cilkexample.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:36:25: error: bits/types.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/stdio.h:161:28: error: bits/stdio_lim.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/stdio.h:846:30: error: bits/sys_errlist.h: No such file or directo\
ry
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:34,
                 from cilkexample.c:1:
/usr/local/cilk/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.2.4/include/stddef.h:\
214: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘typede\
f’
In file included from cilkexample.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:49: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conve\
rsion before ‘typedef’
```

et cetera, et cetera, et cetera.

Here is the file I attempted to compile with the command `cilk++ -o cilkexample cilkexample.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cilk.h>

int foo() {
    return 100;
}

int bar() {
    return 50;
}

int cilk_main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int x, y;

    x = cilk_spawn foo();
    y = cilk_spawn bar();
    cilk_sync;

    printf("Got %d %d, expecting %d %d\n", x, y, 100, 50);
    return 0;
}
```

Again, I think this has to be a configuration problem.  The code is unmodified from the working version our professor distributed, which I tested on a separate machine.

Last bit of information I can think of is the PATH.

```
******@********:~/Path/To/Cilk$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/cilk/bin/:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like your installation is messed up and you're missing lots of header files, but not all, since your inclusion of stdio.h works.

Comment: @jv42, I think you're right, but I don't know what to do about this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing some headers. You say you are on Ubuntu in which headers are distributed in `xxx-dev` packages.

Googling for some of the headers in your error I found that `bits/types.h` are part of `libc6-dev` on Debian, you should check that you have that package at least.

You should check with your distro in what package the files appear, I don't have a Debian or Ubuntu machine available to check on right now.

**Edit:** I found myself an Ubuntu box and it looks like `libc6-dev` contains all the files listed at least. `dpkg-query -S [file]` gives you package name

Comment: Thanks for your response!  However, `dpkg-query -S bits/types.h` returns `libc6-dev: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h`.  Furthermore, the response to `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev` is that libc6-dev is at its most current version.  It would seem that this removes that possibility?  I've been using this machine for a couple of months now for regular C and C++ development.

Comment: In that case I would try a force reinstall of that package